# I need a PID Controller reversed

Tags: c, embedded, pid-controller

I need a pid controller that has to be larger at a lower setpoint than the input and then at a higher setpoint exactly the other way around

```c
double pidEEVOverheating(double setpoint, double input)
{
  static double integral = 0.5;
  static double prev_error = 0.5;

  // Calculate the error
  double error = setpoint - input;

  // Calculate the integral term (accumulation of errors)
  integral += error;

  // Calculate the derivative term (rate of change of the error)
  double derivative = error - prev_error;
  prev_error = error;
  // Calculate the PID output
  double output = Kp * error + Ki * integral + Kd * derivative;

  test5 = output;


  // Limit the output to the allowed range (0 to 540)
  if (output < 0.0)
  {
    output = 0.0;
  }
  else if (output > 100.0)
  {
    output = 100.0;
  }

  return output;
}
```

Normal: If the setpoint is higher than the input, the output becomes larger
What I need: If the setpoint is higher than the input, the output becomes lower

Comment: How does this not do what you want? If setpoint is less than input then error will be negative. Pretty sure your output will be lower in that case. Otherwise can you explain with example input values what you get as an output value and what you expect?

Comment: Try `double error = input - setpoint;` for a reverse PID.

Comment: soooo `return 100 - output;` ?

Comment: Another option would be to use negative gains ("k"-values).